# Combining last-of-type and hover

Tags: css, hover, css-selectors

I have the following html structure:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#"> Superlevel 1 </a>
        <span class="actions">Somes actions</span>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Level 1 </a>
                <span class="actions">Other actions</span>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Sub-Level1</a>
                        <span class="actions">Sub Level actions</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Sub-Level1</a>
                        <span class="actions">Sub Level actions</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    <li>
</ul>
```

The css is this:

```
.treeview li .actions {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 15px;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.treeview li:hover > .actions {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

The problem is that when I pass the mouse over the last li (sub-level 1) the .actions of its parents Level1 and Superlevel1 are displayed. I would like only sub-level1 .actions to be displayed.

So I have tried to replace last css block by:

```
.treeview li:hover:last-of-type > .actions {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

but the `last-of-type` pseudo-selector is applied to li not to `li:hover`.

Any idea of how to combine these two pseudo-selectors ?

Comment: You may have misunderstood how `:last-of-type` works. See http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#last-of-type-pseudo

Comment: Assuming that treeview is the class of the root ul: .treeview li:hover:last-of-type - will select the last li in **each list** (on hover of course)

Comment: @Danield and BoltClock OK I understand better the selector now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you are hovering over the inner `li` list item, you are also hovering over the outer `li` item.  So when the rule

```
ul.treeview > li > ul > li:hover
```

is matched, the following rule also matches:

```
ul.treeview > li:hover
```

What you need is a way to say "I'm hovering over the sub-item and not over the parent item," and I think the easiest way to do it is to modify the html (sorry!).

Since each `li` contains all of its sub-items, you shouldn't be using the `:hover` attribute on the `li`.  Instead, make an element that only contains the things you actually want the `:hover` to apply to:

```
<ul class="treeview">
  <li>
    <div class="itemcontent">
      <a href="#">Level 1</a>
      <span class="actions">Action A</span>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="itemcontent">
          <a href="#">Level 2</a>
          <span class="actions">Action B</span>
        </div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <div class="itemcontent">
              <a href="#">Level 3</a>
              <span class="actions">Action C</span>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="itemcontent">
              <a href="#">Level 3</a>
              <span class="actions">Action D</span>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

So in this example, I used a `<div class="itemcontent">` to wrap just the stuff I want to apply to my hover target.  Then the CSS is very similar to what you had, except replace `li:hover` with `.itemcontent:hover`.

```
.treeview .actions {
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 15px;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.treeview .itemcontent:hover > .actions {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/H8B5P/

Answer (score 0):

You could base your selector on your `a` instead of your `li` and use a sybling selector like this:

```
.treeview a:hover + .actions {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/LT5H3/)

Comment: I had tried this but it works but I can not click on the actions because the hovre i not on the a anymore